# Error while trying to validate XML in Java

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd

I'm trying to validate one xml that I create with a local schema, but some freak error is throwing. My code:

```
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
factory.setValidating(true);
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");

factory.setSchema(schemaFactory.newSchema(
   new Source[] {new StreamSource("\\.\\schema\\xsd_me_ene_diaria.xsd")}));
```

And my stack trace is the follow.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This parser does not support specification "null" version "null"
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.setSchema(Unknown Source)
at SaxValidacao.validateSchema(SaxValidacao.java:36)
```

The error throws just after setSchema is called.

Some clue or another tip for XML validation in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing that sometimes happens is mixing of different versions of the parser. If you use java 5 or higher, try removing references to any external xalan or xerces libraries. (All you need to process xml is included in the standard distribution of java 5)

Comment: Exactly! I had a incorrect lib being referenced. After your I realized this!

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution in a CodeWall article, add one line Java code to your codebase.

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory","com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl");
```

Please refer  to get more detail: https://coderwall.com/p/kqsrrw/jdom2-this-parser-does-not-support-specification-null-version-null

Answer (score 1):

Can you turn off validation and parse the stream?  If yes, it's not likely to be a JAR conflict.

I'm thinking that your issue is access to the schema.

Answer (score 1):

A possible issue is that your JAXP parser is very old and doesn't support setSchema method. Look at the [javadoc](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParserFactory.html) for SAXParsesrFactory. For setSchema (and many other methods), it says:

> **Throws:**
>
> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
>   - For backward compatibility, when implementations for earlier versions
>   of JAXP is used, this exception will
>   be thrown.

Check the parser implementation that you are using and try updating to a newer version.